# How to send Post data in WebView [Xamarin.Forms (Portable)]

Tags: android, post, webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to send the `Post` data to the server and wants to display the response in HTML response in `WebView` I was trying to do it using the `HttpRequestMessage` but unfortunately Xamarin.Forms.WebView doesn't have the `Navigate` method.

Is it possible to do with the Xamarin.Forms.WebView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Send Post request with `HttpClient` and then try to put html string response into `Source` property of `WebView`

Comment: Okay, Let me give it a try.

Comment: Did this work? Or not?